# How to update msi Registry Table Key of Type RegPath

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, windows-installer

I am updating and inserting some tables on an msi file.My issue  is the registry table is having a **key** column which is of type **RegPath**.Internally it is a string but i am unable to insert or retrieve the key attribute.It throws sql exception.

```
string query = "SELECT Name FROM Registry";
WindowsInstaller.View view1 = db3.OpenView(query);
view1.Execute(null);   

Record r1 = vw6.Fetch();
while (r1 != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r1.get_StringData(1));
    r1 = vw6.Fetch();
}
```

This code will work.But if do the same thing for **key**,it is throwing sql exception.

```
string query = "INSERT into Registry(Registry,Root,Key,Name,Value,Component_) VALUES ('" + registryname + "',2,'Software\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components','name','value','" + compname + "')";
WindowsInstaller.View view1 = db3.OpenView(query);
view1.Execute(null);
```

I think the issue is with **key** column which is not a string which is causing the issue.I am attaching the msdn documentation for Registry Table.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168(v=vs.85).aspx
and also for RegPath datatype https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371173(v=vs.85).aspx

Found another post with the same issue.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/352198-issues-in-insert-values-into-msi-database/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you need the double slashes in that registry string - this isn't going to be parsed by a compiler, it's just a raw string, and it looks fine for a registry path if you look at other examples.

However it's more likely that you need to properly escape the keywords with the  peck marks, called acute or grave characters, as in the examples here that I can't type in the post:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368562(v=vs.85).aspx

where both the table and the item are escaped with the peck marks (left of 1 on my keyboard).

The issue is related to ambiguity with SQL syntax, that's the reason for escaping the actual names with peck marks, and Key is certainly already a SQL reserved word.